# Hardinfo doesn't display anything in the "Sensors" section

Tags: 12.04, hardware, monitor, sensors

Is there a way to make Hardinfo to display results on "Sensors" section?Currently as much long I wait it doesn't display anything.I have installed lm-sensors if that matters,but still nothing.

Comment: I still have the same problem and the accepted answer about lm-sensors didn't resolved the problem. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 (ElementaryOS Loki).

Comment: What message do you receive when you execute the command "sensors" ?

Comment: I receive the following: http://paste.ubuntu.com/20808637/

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I have tried many different things to make it work but with no success. If you don't mind you can ask also on launchpad. They might be able to help you there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hardinfo uses `lm-sensors` for the sensors section. To view anything here you need to first install `lm-sensors`.

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

After that you will need to set up the sensors:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Just follow what it says. I always just trust it knows what it's doing and say yes to all the test, etc. Just make sure that you say yes to save it's findings, as it defaults to no. Now restart the sensors service:

```
  sudo service module-init-tools start
```

Use the following command to see if it found valid sensors and you can use them:

```
sensors
```

Here is what mine said:

```
sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +30.0°C  (high = +89.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:       +28.0°C  (high = +89.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

nct6775-isa-0680
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:        +0.95 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:          +0.75 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
AVCC:         +3.36 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
+3.3V:        +3.36 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in4:          +1.26 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:          +0.78 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:          +1.05 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
3VSB:         +3.34 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
Vbat:         +3.31 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 2)  ALARM
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 2)  ALARM
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 2)  ALARM
fan4:           0 RPM  (div = 2)  ALARM
SYSTIN:       +31.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = diode
CPUTIN:       +33.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = diode
AUXTIN:       +23.5°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
cpu0_vid:    +2.050 V
intrusion0:  OK
```

If it didn't find any sensors, it will say:

```
No sensors found!
Make sure you loaded all the kernel drivers you need.
Try sensors-detect to find out which these are.
```

If it spits out some values, then you will now see these when running hardinfo. If not, you can try going through the `sensors-detect` again.

I see that you already installed lm_sensors, but I left that part in for anyone else who happens upon this question.

Comment: Still can't get anything on hardinfo on the "Sensors" section.

Comment: The output that you get when you type `sensors` has more details than mine.Mine only displays temperatures and the fan speed.

Comment: `acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +42.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C) `

`thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        1977 RPM`

`coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +44.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +44.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +42.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +41.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +42.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)`

Comment: So the command `sensors` is working, but the sensors section in hardinfo isn't showing anything? The reason mine shows more info is just because my motherboard must support more sensors, or it's sensors are better supported by Linux.

Comment: ok.Probably I won't manage to get it work in my laptop.Thanks for your help anyway.